# How to chain fade animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, chaining

I have 3 `UILabels` that I want to fade out, one after the other after a couple of seconds. My problem is these are happening all at once. I am trying to chain the animations, but I cannot get this to work. I've tried all sorts of suggestions but to no avail. I know it cannot be this hard. I preferably would like to bundle these together in one animation method, because I would like to trigger other functionality from the `animationDidStop` after all 3 labels have been displayed. Any help or suggestions??

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self fadeAnimation:@"fadeAnimation" finished:YES target:lblReady];
    [self fadeAnimation:@"fadeAnimation" finished:YES target:lblSet];
    [self fadeAnimation:@"fadeAnimation" finished:YES target:lblGo];
}


- (void)fadeAnimation:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished target:(UIView *)target
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:animationID context:(__bridge void *)(target)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    [target setAlpha:0.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];    
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be easier with the latest `UIView` animation methods:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^ {
    lblReady.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^ {
        lblSet.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^ {
            lblGo.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Add your final post-animation code here
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: I just added a comment to the code where you would add your final code to be done after the last animation is done.

Comment: How to cancel all the three animations?

Comment: @GongPengjun Please do a search on canceling a `UIView` animation. If needed, post your own question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

You should have them performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instead.

So change your code to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(fadeAnimation:) withObject:lblReady afterDelay:0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(fadeAnimation:) withObject:lblSet afterDelay:2];
    [self performSelector:@selector(fadeAnimation:) withObject:lblGo afterDelay:4];
}

-(void)fadeAnimation:(UIView *)target {
    [self fadeAnimation:@"fadeAnimation finished:YES target:target];
}




- (void)fadeAnimation:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished target:(UIView *)target
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:animationID context:(__bridge void *)(target)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    [target setAlpha:0.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];    
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This just calls each action code after 0, 2, or 4 sections. If the animation duration is changed, those numbers should be changed correspondingly.

If you want to use block animations instead of using the old animation style, you could instead do:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations ^{
    //put your animations in here
} completion ^(BOOL finished) {
    //put anything that happens after animations are done in here.
    //could be another animation block to chain animations
}];
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Comment: Please note that the use of these old `UIView` animation methods are documented as being "discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later". Also note that due to inexact method timing, you may still have animation overlaps. And you need yet another call to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to run the code you want after the last label fades.

Comment: Ya I just kept that type of code because I figured there was most likely some reason that he was still using it. Otherwise, I would always prefer to use the block method of animation.

Comment: I am new to objective-c so I am not familiar with the best practices. Could you please provide me with a example of block method animation?? I would really appreciate it! Sounds like this is the better approach. Thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy's code example was how to do it using block animations. I will update the answer to include a comment about them.